# Am I using Bayesian or Frequentist Statistics?

Tags: bayesian, biostatistics, frequentist

How do I know if I am using Bayesian or frequentist statistics?

Edit: Sorry about not having enough details. The data analyses I do are things like t-tests, ANOVAS, etc. I do use p-values, confidence intervals, and such, so I guess it is Frequentist.

Comment: If you don't know, then what difference does it make?

Comment: How could we possibly answer your question without any specific detail? Is this about inference? Statistical learning?

Comment: We don't know, but given the question and my prior belief the odds are in favour you use freq. stats. (ya dawg!)

Comment: Look at the words you are using. If "$p$-value", "confidence interval", etc are there, you are employing a frequentist approach. If the words "prior", "credible interval", "_a posteriori_", or "posterior" appear, you are employing  a Bayesian approach. As the well-known Bayesian statistician I. J. Good remarked, "By their posteriors shall you know them".

Comment: I think that Dilip is at least mentioning some terms that the OP can use to differentiate the methods.  I know the question is vague but we should not make fun of the OP.

Comment: @DilipSarwate why not post that as an answer?

Comment: M. Jourdain: "There's only prose and verse?" ... Philosophy Master: "Well, I think we must suppose it's one or it's the other." ... M. Jourdain: "Well, what do you know about that! These forty years now, I've been speaking in prose without knowing it!"  (Moliere, [*The Bourgeois Gentilhomme*](http://moliere-in-english.com/bourgeois.html))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I understanding differences between Bayesian and frequentist inference correctly?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173068/am-i-understanding-differences-between-bayesian-and-frequentist-inference-correc)

Comment: @whuber: Twice in a fortnight or so I've seen that quotation: [what are the odds](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3207/17230)?

Answer (score 1):

Any statistical model (e.g. t-test, ANOVA, regression) can theoretically be analyzed by either frequentist or Bayesian methods.  (In practice, some models are prohibitive to analyze by one technique or the other).

If you don't know whether you analyses are frequentist or Bayesian, they are most likely frequentist--most standard introductions to statistics are written from a frequentist perspective.

In a nutshell, if you are calculating the long-term frequency of obtaining a result as extreme as yours under repeated data collection and analysis, assuming some null hypothesis is true, then you are practicing frequentist statistics.  This is where p-values come from.

If you are making inference about the probability that a parameter falls within some range, based on your prior information about the parameter as well as some data you've collected, then you are practicing Bayesian statistics.